# CakePHP Performance with multiple foreign keys

Tags: performance, cakephp, apache2, cpu

I have a rating system which will score or qualify about 20 fields along with other data.  The problem may be more of a design problem, but cake is certainly not handling it well causing apache2 to spike my CPU.

I have a table called recommendations which is a simple ID, Name.  This table is populated with something like this:

1 - Correct
2 - Incorrect
3 - Missing
4 - NA

The review table has a number of fields that are foreign keys to the recommendations table.

Field 1 - Field20 reference recommendations ID

What I see is that every page request will spike the CPU (apache2 consumes anywhere from 50-90% CPU) even when I'm not hitting a page that would reference reviews.

I'm guessing this has to do with the way cake handles model bindings.  I could use something like enum but that is not as flexible.

Any thoughts on a better design or how to debug why cake is making Apache go crazy?

```
var $name = 'Review';
var $actsAs = array('Containable');

var $validate = array(
    'service_request' => array(
        'minLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 8),
            'message' => 'Enter a valid Service Request Number'
        ),
        'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 8),
            'message' => 'Enter a valid Service Request Number'
        ),
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'numeric',
            'message' => 'Enter a valid Service Request Number'
        )
    )
);

var $belongsTo = array(
    'Employee' => array(
        'className' => 'Employee',
        'foreignKey' => 'reviewer_id',
    ),
    'Reviewer' => array(
        'className' => 'Employee',
        'foreignKey' => 'reviewer_id'
    ),
    'Reviewee' => array(
        'className' => 'Employee',
        'foreignKey' => 'reviewee_id'
    ),
    'Rating' => array(
        'className' => 'Rating',
        'foreignKey' => 'rating_id',
    ),
    'SrSummary' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_summary'
    ),
    'SrProduct' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_product'
    ),
    'SrVersion' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_version'
    ),
    'SrRelease' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_release'
    ),
    'SrComponent' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_component'
    ),
    'SrTechnicalProblem' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_technical_problem'
    ),
    'SrCommunicationOwner' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_communication_owner'
    ),
    'SrCommunicationGroup' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_communication_group'
    ),
    'SrOwnerGroup' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_owner_group'
    ),
    'SrOwnerGroupGeo' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_owner_group_geo'
    ),
    'SrStatus' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_status'
    ),
    'SrSubstatus' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_substatus'
    ),
    'SrSeverity' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_severity'
    ),
    'SrPriority' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_priority'
    ),
    'SrHwPlatform' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_hwplatform'
    ),
    'SrBuild' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_build'
    ),
    'SrSerial' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_serial'
    ),
    'SrManualSerial' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
        'foreignKey' => 'sr_manual_serial'
    ),
    'Note' => array(
        'className' => 'Note',
        'foreignKey' => 'note_id'
    ),
    'Timing' => array(
        'className' => 'Timing',
        'foreignKey' => 'timing_id'
    )
);
```

Comment: It sounds like you are guessing. Have you reviewed the logs to see what they say?

Comment: I'm not guessing, I took the application apart and rebuilt it piece by piece.  I already had a strong suspicion.  If I remove the $belongsTo associations to the recommendations table in the review model the problem goes away.  I've also looked at my apache logs and nothing stands out as a problem.

Comment: You said in your post, `I'm guessing this has to do with the way cake handles model bindings.` Anyways, can you share some code where you `guess` the problem is occurring?

Comment: I've updated with the basic review model.  As you see there are a number of associations to 'Recommendation'.   I agree with your logic below but this is not the case.  I have a dashboard controller that runs custom queries that doesn't even touch reviews.  I run into the same problem.  Again, if I remove the above associations to Recommendations the CPU issues go away.

Comment: I did some profiling with xdebug and do find most of the time spent in classregistry::init.  I found that I can remove the $hasMany array in the Recommendation model and the performance is much improved.  I tested saving data and it worked without issue.  I thought Cake would need both the $belongsTo and $hasMany defined to function properly.  It seems only using $belongsTo is working and eliminating the performance issue.

Comment: Not sure how big your database is yet, but have you made sure you have proper indexing set up.

Comment: Ryan, yes, I'm using InnoDB as the database engine.  The database isn't huge yet, but will grow pretty large over time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a controller that is referring to all the reviews. You need to disable associations when you pull the data when it is not required. You haven't shown any code but it will look something like this before you run the query.

```
$this->Model->recursive = -1;
```

Comment: I've tried this, but makes no difference.  What I can potentially do is remove the model associations and use bindModel only when needed, but this still causes the performance hit when accessing this model.  Seems cake doesn't handle the multiple associations on the same table very well. I'm trying to work through xdebug to see if I can pinpoint anything further.  I thought maybe Auth was doing some extra searching joining potentially causing problems but I've ruled that out by disabling Auth completely.  If anyone else has seen anything like this or has any other ideas please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without being able to debug your site, but - a few things.

If you're not already using [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit), get it.  Then you can easily look at any/all mysql queries running as well as how long they each took.

The CPU spike(s) likely has to do with running a query that's pulling way too much information (ie too much associated data).  Get the correct version of [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) depending on what version of Cake you're running, and look at all the queries and how long they take to run, then tweak your associations or recursive level, or contains...etc to keep from getting the excess data.

(Or, if you get to the point where you know a specific query is the issue, but can't figure out why, post that as another StackOverflow question)

---

**Unrelated note:**

The "normal" way to set up the kind of associations you're doing with Reviews, would be to just have a `'foreign_key'`, and a `'model'` field in your review table, then set your associations up using those - something like this:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Employee' => array(
        'className' => 'Employee',
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => array('Review.model' => 'Employee')
    ),
    //...
```

That way, if you ever add another model, you can link to it without having to add yet another field to the reviews table.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'll definitely check out DebugKit.  For now just removing the $hasMany in Recommendation has resolved my issue.  I don't really need that as I'll likely never be pulling associated data from that model/controller.  Not sure I completely follow the association example you're providing.

Comment: Jeff - basically, you don't need a separate field for each model - you use the model/foreign_key fields to determine which item/model the review is associated with.

Comment: Jeff - DebugKit is almost a must - everyone I know just gets it by default when they start a new project.  Once you use it, you'll wonder how you ever lived without it.